# What is the VINTF manifest in android studio? Have an error

Tags: java, android

> 2020-04-22 16:14:49.759 1809-1809/? E/servicemanager: Could not find android.hardware.power.IPower/default in the VINTF manifest.

This keeps popping up. Am coding a camera, that when a button is clicked, an image is cropped.

Here is a custom view I am adding to a fragment.

public class DrawView extends View {

```
Point[] points = new Point[4];

/**
 * point1 and point 3 are of same group and same as point 2 and point4
 */
int groupId = -1;
private ArrayList<ColorBall> colorballs = new ArrayList<>();

private int mStrokeColor = Color.parseColor("#AADB1255");
private int mFillColor = Color.parseColor("#55DB1255");
private Rect mCropRect = new Rect();

// array that holds the balls
private int balID = 0;
// variable to know what ball is being dragged
Paint paint;

public DrawView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, -1);
}

public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    paint = new Paint();
    setFocusable(true); // necessary for getting the touch events
}

private void initRectangle(int X, int Y) {
    //initialize rectangle.
    points[0] = new Point();
    points[0].x = X - 200;
    points[0].y = Y - 100;

    points[1] = new Point();
    points[1].x = X;
    points[1].y = Y + 30;

    points[2] = new Point();
    points[2].x = X + 30;
    points[2].y = Y + 30;

    points[3] = new Point();
    points[3].x = X + 30;
    points[3].y = Y;

    balID = 2;
    groupId = 1;
    // declare each ball with the ColorBall class
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        colorballs.add(new ColorBall(getContext(), R.drawable.gray_circle, points[i], i));
    }
}

// the method that draws the balls
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if(points[3]==null) {
        //point4 null when view first create
        initRectangle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
    }

    int left, top, right, bottom;
    left = points[0].x;
    top = points[0].y;
    right = points[0].x;
    bottom = points[0].y;
    for (int i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
        left = left > points[i].x ? points[i].x : left;
        top = top > points[i].y ? points[i].y : top;
        right = right < points[i].x ? points[i].x : right;
        bottom = bottom < points[i].y ? points[i].y : bottom;
    }
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5);

    //draw stroke
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setColor(mStrokeColor);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(2);

    mCropRect.left = left + colorballs.get(0).getWidthOfBall() / 2;
    mCropRect.top = top + colorballs.get(0).getWidthOfBall() / 2;
    mCropRect.right = right + colorballs.get(2).getWidthOfBall() / 2;
    mCropRect.bottom = bottom + colorballs.get(3).getWidthOfBall() / 2;
    canvas.drawRect(mCropRect, paint);

    //fill the rectangle
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(mFillColor);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
    canvas.drawRect(mCropRect, paint);

    // draw the balls on the canvas
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setTextSize(18);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
    for (int i =0; i < colorballs.size(); i ++) {
        ColorBall ball = colorballs.get(i);
        canvas.drawBitmap(ball.getBitmap(), ball.getX(), ball.getY(),
                paint);

        canvas.drawText("" + (i+1), ball.getX(), ball.getY(), paint);
    }
}

// events when touching the screen
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int eventAction = event.getAction();

    int X = (int) event.getX();
    int Y = (int) event.getY();

    switch (eventAction) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // touch down so check if the finger is on
            // a ball
            if (points[0] == null) {
                initRectangle(X, Y);
            } else {
                //resize rectangle
                balID = -1;
                groupId = -1;
                for (int i = colorballs.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
                    ColorBall ball = colorballs.get(i);
                    // check if inside the bounds of the ball (circle)
                    // get the center for the ball
                    int centerX = ball.getX() + ball.getWidthOfBall();
                    int centerY = ball.getY() + ball.getHeightOfBall();
                    paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                    // calculate the radius from the touch to the center of the
                    // ball
                    double radCircle = Math
                            .sqrt((double) (((centerX - X) * (centerX - X)) + (centerY - Y)
                                    * (centerY - Y)));

                    if (radCircle < ball.getWidthOfBall()) {

                        balID = ball.getID();
                        if (balID == 1 || balID == 3) {
                            groupId = 2;
                        } else {
                            groupId = 1;
                        }
                        invalidate();
                        break;
                    }
                    invalidate();
                }
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: // touch drag with the ball

            if (balID > -1) {
                // move the balls the same as the finger
                colorballs.get(balID).setX(X);
                colorballs.get(balID).setY(Y);

                paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                if (groupId == 1) {
                    colorballs.get(1).setX(colorballs.get(0).getX());
                    colorballs.get(1).setY(colorballs.get(2).getY());
                    colorballs.get(3).setX(colorballs.get(2).getX());
                    colorballs.get(3).setY(colorballs.get(0).getY());
                } else {
                    colorballs.get(0).setX(colorballs.get(1).getX());
                    colorballs.get(0).setY(colorballs.get(3).getY());
                    colorballs.get(2).setX(colorballs.get(3).getX());
                    colorballs.get(2).setY(colorballs.get(1).getY());
                }

                invalidate();
            }

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // touch drop - just do things here after dropping
            break;
    }
    // redraw the canvas
    invalidate();
    return true;
}

public Drawable doTheCrop(Bitmap sourceBitmap) throws IOException {

    //Bitmap sourceBitmap = null;
    //Drawable backgroundDrawable = getBackground();
    /*
    if (backgroundDrawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) backgroundDrawable;
        if(bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
            sourceBitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        }
    }*/
        //source bitmap was scaled, you should calculate the rate
        float widthRate = ((float) sourceBitmap.getWidth()) / getWidth();
        float heightRate =  ((float) sourceBitmap.getHeight()) / getHeight();

        //crop the source bitmap with rate value
        int left = (int) (mCropRect.left * widthRate);
        int top = (int) (mCropRect.top * heightRate);
        int right = (int) (mCropRect.right * widthRate);
        int bottom = (int) (mCropRect.bottom * heightRate);
        Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap, left, top, right - left, bottom - top);
        Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), croppedBitmap);
        return drawable;
        /*
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_dashboard);
        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.capture);
        if (btn == null){
            System.out.println("NULL");
        }
        try{
            btn.setText("HI");
        }
        catch (Exception e){

        }
        //setBackground(drawable);*/
        //savebitmap(croppedBitmap);
}



private File savebitmap(Bitmap bmp) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, bytes);
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/" + "testimage.jpg");
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "YUP", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    f.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
    fo.close();
    return f;
}

public static class ColorBall {

    Bitmap bitmap;
    Context mContext;
    Point point;
    int id;

    public ColorBall(Context context, int resourceId, Point point, int id) {
        this.id = id;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                resourceId);
        mContext = context;
        this.point = point;
    }

    public int getWidthOfBall() {
        return bitmap.getWidth();
    }

    public int getHeightOfBall() {
        return bitmap.getHeight();
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return bitmap;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return point.x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return point.y;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        point.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        point.y = y;
    }
}
```

}

Here is the fragment that I have added a camera do, basically the main part of the application that I am working on.

```
public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment {

private DashboardViewModel dashboardViewModel;

//All my constants
private DrawView mDrawView;
private Drawable imgDraw;
private TextureView txtView;
private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();

static{
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 180);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
}

private String cameraID;
private String pathway;
CameraDevice cameraDevice;
CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession;
CaptureRequest captureRequest;
CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder;
private Size imageDimensions;
private ImageReader imageReader;
private File file;
Handler mBackgroundHandler;
HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    dashboardViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(DashboardViewModel.class);

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);

    try{
        txtView = (TextureView)root.findViewById(R.id.textureView);
        txtView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
        mDrawView = root.findViewById(draw_view);
        Button cap = (Button)root.findViewById(R.id.capture);
        cap.setClickable(true);
        cap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    Log.i("HOLA","HOLA");
                    takePicture();
                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Log.i("HI",e.toString());
    }
    /*
    txtView = (TextureView)root.findViewById(R.id.textureView);
    txtView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
    mDrawView = root.findViewById(R.id.draw_view);
    Button cap = (Button)root.findViewById(R.id.capture);
    cap.setClickable(true);
    cap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                Log.i("HOLA","HOLA");
                takePicture();
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });*/
    return root;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults){
    if (requestCode == 101){
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Permission is required",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }
}
TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener textureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {

        try {
            openCamera();
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {

    }
};

private final CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
        cameraDevice = camera;
        try {
            createCameraPreview();
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
        cameraDevice.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice, int i) {
        cameraDevice.close();
        cameraDevice = null;

    }
};

private void createCameraPreview() throws CameraAccessException {
    SurfaceTexture texture = txtView.getSurfaceTexture(); //?
    texture.setDefaultBufferSize(imageDimensions.getWidth(), imageDimensions.getHeight());
    Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
    captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
    captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
    cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
            if (cameraDevice == null){
                return;
            }
            cameraCaptureSession = session;
            try {
                updatePreview();
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "CONFIGURATION", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }, null);
}

private void updatePreview() throws CameraAccessException {
    if (cameraDevice == null){
        return;
    }
    captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
    cameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
}

private void openCamera() throws CameraAccessException {

    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    cameraID = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
    CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraID);
    StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
    imageDimensions = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 101);
        return;
    }
    manager.openCamera(cameraID, stateCallback, null);
}

private void takePicture() throws CameraAccessException {

    if (cameraDevice == null) {
        Log.i("NOt working", "hi");
        return;
    }
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice.getId());
    Size[] jpegSizes = null;
    jpegSizes = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP).getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);
    int width = 640;
    int height = 480;
    if (jpegSizes != null && jpegSizes.length > 0) {
        width = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
        height = jpegSizes[0].getHeight();
    }
    final ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
    List<Surface> outputSurfaces = new ArrayList<>(2);
    outputSurfaces.add(reader.getSurface());
    outputSurfaces.add(new Surface(txtView.getSurfaceTexture()));
    final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
    captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
    captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
    int rotation = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
    Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
    String ts = tsLong.toString();
    file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + ts + ".jpg");
    pathway = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + ts + ".jpg";
    //cameraDevice.close();


    ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader imageReader) {
            Image image = null;

            //image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
            image = reader.acquireNextImage();
            ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
            buffer.get(bytes);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes , 0, bytes.length);
            try {
                Drawable back = mDrawView.doTheCrop(bitmap);
                Button btn = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.capture);
                btn.setBackground(back);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            /*
            try {
                save(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (image != null){
                    image.close();
                }

            }*/


        }

    };

    reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener, mBackgroundHandler);
    final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback(){
        @Override
        public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result){
            super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
            try {
                createCameraPreview();
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
            try {
                session.capture(captureBuilder.build(), captureListener, mBackgroundHandler);
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {

        }
    }, mBackgroundHandler);

}

private void save (byte[] bytes) throws IOException {

    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    outputStream.write(bytes);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),pathway,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    outputStream.close();

    imgDraw = Drawable.createFromPath(pathway);
    //mDrawView.doTheCrop(imgDraw);
}


@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    startBackgroundThread();
    if (txtView.isAvailable()){
        try {
            openCamera();
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else{
        txtView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
    }
}

private void startBackgroundThread() {

    mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("Camera Background");
    mBackgroundThread.start();
    mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
}

protected void stopBackgroundThread() throws InterruptedException{
    mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
    mBackgroundThread.join();
    mBackgroundThread = null;
    mBackgroundHandler = null;
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    try {
        stopBackgroundThread();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

}

Here is the xml file for that fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment">

<TextureView
    android:id = "@+id/textureView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<com.PeavlerDevelopment.OpinionMinion.ui.dashboard.DrawView
    android:id="@+id/draw_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/capture"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"></Button>



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The problem seems to lie somewhere in the doCrop method of the DrawView class.

If there is anything else that would help make the problem more clear, let me know! I will gladly share the github repo with you.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in [Android Design Documenation](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/vintf/objects) the VINTF stands for Vendor Interface and its a Manifest structure to aggregate data form the device. That specific log means that your manifest is missing something like this:

```xml
     <hal>
        <name>android.hardware.power</name>
        <transport>hwbinder</transport>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <interface>
            <name>IPower</name>
            <instance>default</instance>
        </interface>
     </hal>
```

which basically is hardware power information. 
I think it's not related to what you are trying to do, but I need more info than that log.

Comment: Hi, I added some more code to my problem. Let me know if you need anymore code to look at. Any help is appreciated, I'm very new to this so seriously thank you!